# Was there a giant red-haired race in North America?

Tags: anthropology, archaeology

The other day, I saw a show on the History channel about "giant skeletons" being found in North America. It also said that, for some reason, these findings have been hidden from people, maybe due to them being hoaxes or something else.

According to the [*new illuminati* blog](http://nexusilluminati.blogspot.mx/2011/03/who-were-red-haired-giants-of-early.html) they have found 12ft (3.65m) skeletons. A lot of these skeletons have been [found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si-Te-Cah) in [Nevada](http://garry-nelson.hubpages.com/hub/Human-Giants). There is another [documented case in Texas](http://stevequayle.com/Giants/N.Am/Victoria.Cty.TX.giant.html).

Other sources state that there's been a finding with several bodies together:

[The Ooparts Collection: *There Were Giants in Those Days*](http://s8int.com/giants3.html):

> A mound near Toledo, Ohio, held 20 skeletons, seated and facing east
>   with jaws and teeth "twice as large as those of present day people,"
>   and besides each was a large bowl with "curiously wrought hieroglyphic
>   figures." (Chicago Record, Oct. 24, 1895; cited by Ron G. Dobbins,
>   NEARA Journal, v13, fall 1978)

and [Urban Titan: *5 Most Mysterious Ancient Discoveries*](http://urbantitan.com/5-most-mysterious-ancient-discoveries/):

> In 1895 in Toledo, Ohio 20 giant skeletons were found seated with jaws
>   and teeth twice as large as a normal skeleton’s. Yet another giant
>   skeleton was unearthed in 1928 by a farmer in Louisiana. This skeleton
>   was 9 feet 11 inches. Many claims have been made about these abnormal
>   skeletons, the majority of people claiming they belong to the
>   mysterious Sasquatch.

Finally [ArticleSafari: *Who were the red-haired giants of early North America?*](http://www.articlesafari.com/2010/10/red-haired-giants-north-america/) says that real encounters were logged by Magellan.

Although there seems to be a lot of information out there, unfortunately none of the sites that I found has references. So I'm not sure how reliable the information is. Was there a giant red-haired  race in North America?

[image: Jaw comparison: Human vs. "Giant"][image: Scull comparison: Human vs. "Giant"]

Comment: I edited your post to show the link target and not just "this page" etc. You should always avoid "this" and "here" links. Instead use the name/title of the website or paper, which is a lot more readable and informative.

Comment: [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJQFQVYK67A) shows __The Bible Skeptic__'s quest to find the truth behind the Nevada "giants".

Comment: btw, the [Square-Cube-Law](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SquareCubeLaw) limits the size of humans

Comment: Good god, put a warning on that new illuminati blog link.  It WILL make your eyes bleed...  (Staggers off to try and clean the blood out of his eyes...)

Comment: I do not buy the square cubes law... I prefer the right Triangle hypotenuse!

Comment: @Ardesco: [It could be worse!](http://www.rasputin.de/CF/Jugend/)

Comment: @MartinScharrer OH DEAR MERCIFUL ATHIESMO MY EYES

Comment: Acromegaly [runs in families](http://www.springerimages.com/Images/MedicineAndPublicHealth/1-10.1007_s11102-008-0138-y-2?iact=hc&vpx=579&vpy=124&dur=4890&hovh=276&hovw=182&tx=99&ty=152&sig=108839229321958720072&ei=k75LULrUB4m2hAfw44DQCg&page=2&tbnh=137&tbnw=92&start=22&ndsp=31&ved=1t:429,r:26,s:22,i:265). Maybe the heights in those reports have been a tad exaggerated... and the mistery is easily solved.

Comment: Please see Jim Veiera's research...most of the information he's uncovered has been identified in the past year. Looks indeed like there is a wealth of historic documents and accounts of the unearthing of these skeletons which has not made it into the wide public arena. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eNjm4_moFE

Comment: I don't see how we could prove it wrong for no research papers could be published if it is the case. However, after extensive research on Scholar database I found absolutely nothing claiming these giants existed. I think that such a discovery would have attracted curiosity of researchers resulting in at least a dozen of papers...

Comment: @RVS I would point out to you that History Channel is not a reliable source. They'll post anything that might relate to history if it'll bring in ratings no matter how factual it is. If real it would be a major find, and it's a safe bet that anything really far out that's reported by non-reputable sources is a hoax of some kind. I'd also point out that the tallest known human was under 9 feet and he didn't exactly have a long healthy life.

Comment: Also the basis of this is ancient Native American myths, and mythology is pretty reliably full of fiction.

Comment: I had never heard of Giants discovered in these places however there has been mention of giant people that inhabited the Mounds in the plain states.  St. Louis was the [City of Mounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_St._Louis) before being cleared and built on but in western Illinois there still exist an area of mounds from ancient Native peoples. I don't believe wiki is accurate in assessing how old these mounds were because many were destroyed before an archeological dig could take place.

Comment: [national geographic article on Cahokia supporting my above comment](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2011/01/cahokia/hodges-text)

Comment: Oh, History Channel, I weep for thee...

Answer (score 4):

As is often the case, **No, but with a grain of truth**.

There *was* a tribe which was described in legend as "red-headed cannibals" by the oral history of the [Paiute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paiute) tribe: the [Si-Te-Cah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si-Te-Cah).  According to their legend, as documented in *Fossil Legends of the First Americans* ([2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-691-11345-9)) and [Sarah Winnemucca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Winnemucca) of the Paiute tribe in her autobiography (1883), the Paiute fought them and killed them all, *possibly* by sealing the survivors into [Lovelock Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovelock_Cave#Si-Te-Cah:_The_Legend_of_the_Red-Haired_Giants).

However, there is no original source for these cannibals being giants - Winnemucca doesn't even hint at that in her book.

From the other end, there *were* skeletons discovered in Lovelock Cave, and Wikipedia cites one of the original miners' archeological reports saying he found the ["body of a man six feet six inches tall."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si-Te-Cah#cite_note-5).  This is certainly tall but not a giant by modern standards, but could have been in prehistoric times.  Additionally, human bones which appeared to have been split for marrow were found, which supports the cannibal legend.  However, a lot of the remains are no longer around, due to the lack of care taken with archeological remains in the early 20th century. (One source I found said that one of the skeletons was taken to be ground up for a local lodge's "initiation ritual", for example.)

The aforementioned *Fossil Legends* book suggests that the story of giants

> was started by entrepreneurs setting up tourist displays and that the skeletons themselves were of normal size. However, about a hundred miles north of Lovelock there are plentiful fossils of mammoths and cave bears, and their large limb bones could easily be thought to be those of giants by an untrained observer.