# Were giant human bones discovered in Castelnau?

Tags: history, physiology, anthropology

French anthropologist [Georges Vacher de Lapouge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Vacher_de_Lapouge) (1854 - 1936) reported in 1890 the discovery of "[the Giant of Castelnau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_of_Castelnau)" - giant bones in neolithic tombs, in southern France. According to Mr. de Lapouge, these human bones were those of normal humans (not some case of abnormal growth due to growth hormone disorder).

These discoveries were reported in [some](http://timesmachine.nytimes.com/browser/1892/10/03/) [newspapers](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83016758/1894-10-11/ed-1/seq-2/#words=skulls+Montpellier+France&date1=1894&date2=1896&searchType=advanced&lccn=&proxdistance=5&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=&andtext=montpellier+france+skulls&dateFilterType=yearRange&index=1) and science reviews ([french official archive of "La Nature"](http://cnum.cnam.fr/CGI/fpage.cgi?4KY28.35/15/70/536/0/0), n° 888, 1890). They were taken to the nearest big city, Montpellier, where the University harbours France's oldest and most prestigious medicine school. The bones found by Lapouge where reportedly analyzed by medicine, zoology and paleontology specialists (MM. Sabatier and Delage) who confirmed his early findings.

Lapouge concluded that a race of giant humans had lived in southern France at the time of the glaciations (and that they were contemporaries of the Neanderthal men).

**Is this conclusion (still) supported by any scientific evidence today?**

Comment: somewhat related : http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/was-there-a-giant-red-haired-race-in-north-america

Comment: the discovery of "giant human bones" in ancient Greece gave rise to their mythology of giants, cyclopses, etc. etc.. Of course those were mammoth bones and other large extinct animals. No doubt this is the same thing, a case of mistaken identity, if not deliberate fraud.