# Have giant human skeletons been found?

Tags: archeology

[This article](http://new-cryptozoology.wikia.com/wiki/Giant_Human_Skeletons) shows a diagram of the remains of human giants[image]. The tallest one being 36 ft. (1097.28 cm.) This seems like a pretty large claim for an article that doesn't state any sources. Could there be any legitimacy to these claims?

Comment: To quote A.R. Tesla, "Why do we even *have* the [Square-Cube Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law) ?"

Comment: Also not the sources that are cited are quite old and most of them unlikely to be verifiable. I do however think that if a 15' skeleton had been found in the 1950, it should still be around somewhere.

Comment: For future reference, the word ["cryptozoology"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptozoology) is an indication that anything to follow is almost certainly total crap.  These are the folks who look for Bigfoot and the Loch Ness monster and Yetis.  The presence of the suffix `-ology` is supposed to make it seem more scientific, but it's pseudo science at best.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/was-there-a-giant-red-haired-race-in-north-america?rq=1

Comment: @HopelessN00b I wouldn't say "total crap" but usually you need examine anything with the label with a very skeptical eye.

Comment: Possible explanation that might improve any answers: Were there any fossil discoveries (eg, dinosaur bones, incomplete skeletons) that were _mistaken at the time of discovery_ for gigantic hominids?

Comment: The fact-checking on this article didn't even extend to looking to see if "Caesar" was spelled correctly. Twice.

Comment: Closest I've found of something reputable is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_of_Castelnau which was a small number of bones of extreme proportion. The Wisconsin  find in 1912 was reported in several newspapers, but no pictures or corroborating details. There are, of course, isolated figures of 9-10 feet found, but that's well within human norms.

Comment: Hah! And the site at http://atrueott.wordpress.com/forbidden-archeology/ links to http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2003/02/0205_030205_cyclops.html as claiming discovery of "15 foot tall cyclops" when the NG article is all about a find of mammoths that may have confused the Greeks into making up the cyclops!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. There is no fossil evidence of *any* apes being larger than about 9.8ft tall.

"The fossil record suggests that individuals of the species *Gigantopithecus blacki* were the largest known apes that ever lived, standing up to 3 m (9.8 ft)." (Refs: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gigantopithecus&oldid=612964116), [McMaster University](http://dailynews.mcmaster.ca/article/giant-ape-lived-alongside-humans/)).

Comment: As per the comment by @BrianS in the question itself, is there anything in the historical record of skeletal discoveries at the times indicated that could be an explanation. In other-words, where skeletons of any time found in the cited time frames?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Articuno's answer, the reason no remains of the type have been found is because **adult hominids taller than (about) 9 feet simply can't exist**.

It's about physics: **If you double the height of any being, its surface area quadruples, and its volume triples.** While lengths scale linearly (x), areas scale quadratically (x^2) and volumes scale cubically (x^3). This means that a human as big as those in your examples would not reach adulthood.

The [oldest remains of a person with gigantism](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/11/121102-gigantism-ancient-skeleton-archaeology-history-science-rome/) are those of a man that lived close to Rome in third-century A.D. Gigantism itself is extremely rare (about three people in a million worldwide today).

'Giants' can't exist because it's a [scaling issue](http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/scaling.html). Galileo was one of the first to point it out:

> Galileo begins “Two New Sciences” with the striking observation that
>   if two ships, one large and one small, have identical proportions and
>   are constructed of the same materials, so that one is purely a scaled
>   up version of the other in every respect, nevertheless the larger one
>   will require proportionately more scaffolding and support on launching
>   to prevent its breaking apart under its own weight.

If you double all the dimensions of a stone building supported on stone pillars, the weights are all increased eightfold, but the supporting capacities only go up fourfold. This all applies to animals and humans too:

> (Large) increase in height can be accomplished only by employing a
>   material which is harder and stronger than usual, or by enlarging the
>   size of the bones, thus changing their shape until the form and
>   appearance of the animals suggests a monstrosity.

**If humans were to be doubled in size, for example, their shape would need to change so much they would hardly be considered the same species.**

Comment: This is a good start, but the fact that a maximum size for humans to survive at *exists* doesn't prove that that size is 9 feet. Why is 9 feet the cut-off point?

Comment: *If you double the height of any being, its surface area quadruples, and its volume **triples**.* What ? In my notebook the volume is multiplied by eight, not by three. Must be carelessness because below you correctly mention weight being increased *eightfold*.