# Did Giant Humans exist?

Tags: archeology

I am well aware that [there is a question and answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/21985/have-giant-human-skeletons-been-found) on this site that debunks the existence of giant humans, but I am still fascinated by them when I read [this report](http://www.epicadamwildlife.com/2013/06/29/giant-human-skeleton-discovered).

Usually I am skeptical of these claims, but now we have a youtube video purportedly showing the skull of a GIANT HUMAN, so this does make my belief waver somewhat.

[The giant human youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azjWu6Uva8k)

Is the above report credible? Did giant human ever exist?

Comment: At the moment, this is a direct duplicate. If there really is new evidence that makes the existing question out-of-date (I looked quickly, but couldn't see any), please highlight where it appears in the video. The bit I saw seems to suggest that all they had were photos that had already been debunked as Photoshop.

Comment: @Oddthinking, *suggest that all they had were photos that had already been debunked as Photoshop*, can you tell me where they have been debunked?

Comment: @Graviton - The video/article you linked to makes that claim.

Comment: At the 17-25s mark. It doesn't *accept* the claim, but the bits I say were careful only to repeat claims and never claim them as true.